# Assynchronous dialog box on Windows with C++

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, c++builder

Right now I'm working on a real time software, but I got myself implementing forms - using C++Builder 2007 - for confirmation messages (you know, those dialog box with OK and Cancel or only OK if it's an error), and I read that there's a DialogBox class on Windows MFC. The problem is the calling interrupts the thread until some input is done on the dialog, which I can't afford because another things might be happening on the application.

I've read about Modeless Dialog Box, but I'm not sure it's what I need or how to implement. Is there a default assynchronous dialog box on Windows MFC and if there is, how do I call it?

Comment: You should be using threads. _Never_ do heavy-lifting (cpu intensive) work on the main-ui thread. It's windows 202 (not quite 101, but still quite basic)

Comment: I should be using threads for confirmation messages? So I'd call the Dialog Box on this new thread instead of the main one, and return the value after it's been closed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx#modeless_box

Comment: Do you want to show message boxes like in [CWnd::MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eebkf6f(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: dccarmo: It is usually more common, in Windows, to approach it the other way around:  Your 'work' should be running on a thread, and the Windows UI and dialogs should be popping up on the main thread.  Though either way works.  If you run the UI from a thread then just make sure to do all window creation, message pumping, etc. from the secondary thread.

Comment: @RedSerpent that's exactly what I was looking for, is it non-blocking?

Comment: @AliVeli just noticed the misspell, sorry for that!

Comment: @jstine but how are the secondary threads supposed to update the main while it's hanging waiting for an user confirmation? The main thread is a map and it needs to be updated the moment it receives one.

Comment: @dccarmo no but you can show them from a thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need threads for this, you need modeless dialog boxes... they end up being windows on the same dispatch thread.

Comment: basically instead of creating the object on the stack and using `DoModal()`, you `new` the object then do the `Create` yourself.